# How to change the data to other languages which data are coming from server(php mysql)

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-studio, multilingual

i want to provide option to the user to select or choose language,actually data stored on server is in english language .

when user choose any other language ,the whole application or app data will be change in to that selected language.

i am already visits so many links for do this task .they provide solution to make individul string for all type of data and put it in to values folder .

the main thing is that i want to display data in to different language which is coming throw parsing from the server ,!!

so any one has idea or logic about how to convert that data run time programatically in android.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you heard about this ever? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help you. [Google Cloud Translation API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/)

Answer (score 0):

you have 03 solutions to implement :

1-use the local resources internationalization way, so you can have full control on word definition. Here's a [tuto](https://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-building-multi-language-supported-app/).

2-or use a translator API (not free), here's an [example with Google's](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2009/10/androidtranslate-using-google-translate.html)

3-add extra columns for other languages in each Table you want to load `label`. (not recommended for complex architecture)

eg.:

```
label_en, label_fr, label_it, ...
```

Update every column `label_{language_id}`, then load your data according selected language. This is just a rough idea:

```
function getLabel(languageId){
    if(languageId == 'fr')
       return this.label_fr;
    elseif(...)
       ...
    else
       return this.label_en;
}
```